# How many one in a million people exist?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

So if there are 7,632,819,325 people currently alive (According to google), then how many of those people are "One in a million"? 
My math behind it was to divide the number by a million, but I just wanted to double check. I got the number 7,632; as expected- but this felt a little too easy. (Math has never been my strong suit, lol.) Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your definition of "one in a million."  In a million people, one of them may be the fastest, one of them may be the smartest, one of them may be the tallest, etc...  you could potentially come up with a million different superlatives to quantify them by at which point they are *all* "one in a million."

Comment: If you are referring to something more along the lines of "among a million people, only one is expected to be taller than a certain height" at which point, yes, among the total population of the world there would indeed be an expected $7,632$ people that are taller than that height.

Comment: According to the Discworld books by Terry Pratchett, one in a million chances  come through nine times out of ten. So, the number of one in a million people is 6,869,537,393

Comment: “Scientists have calculated that the chances of something so patently absurd actually existing are millions to one.
But magicians have calculated that million-to-one chances crop up nine times out of ten.”

Comment: Statistically it should be between 7489 and 7777 at 90% confidence.

Comment: Each of those people is "one in 7,632,819,325".  And that is much rarer than one in a million.

Answer (score 4):

For a single trait for a human to possess such that the odds of a single person possessing that trait are "one in a million", then the expected number of people globally to possess that trait would be around 7,632 as you state. But, that is just the expected number. Since this would be a binomial distribution, you are likely to come close to that number, but if you wanted a 95% confidence interval, it would be more like you can be 95% confident that between 7,463 and 7,809 people are "one in a million".